# Add CSS Dynamically Using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, dynamically-generated

I would like to add CSS to an HTML Element dynamically using Prototype JS. I am using below code.

```
var wrapper_content = $('wrapper').innerHTML;
wrapper_content.img.setStyle({display:'inline'});
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Wouldn't `.innerHTML` just return the html inside the `wrapper`-element (which isn't a HTML-element). Try with `console.log($('wrapper'));` and see if it returns anything at all. Otherwise, you might have to check your selector.

Comment: Thanks @NoLifeKing for your reply. I checked `console.log($('wrapper'));` and I can see the HTML element at console. `.innerHTML` is returning HTML content of that element. But I would like to apply css on Images of `wrapper_content`. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these you can use the `invoke()` utility method like so

```
$$('#wrapper img').invoke('setStyle',{'display':'inline'});
```

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/

Answer (score 0):

You could change your selector to `var wrapper_content = $('wrapper img');`

And then you can do like this `wrapper_content.each(function(el) { el.setStyle({ 'display': 'inline' }); });`

Edit: Changed the syntax to work with Prototype JS instead.

Comment: Thanks @NoLifeKing for your reply. You mentioned here jQuery solution but I need Prototype JS solution. Thanks

Comment: Almost right. Prototype uses two dollar signs to signal “return a collection of objects” versus the single dollar sign which is simply shorthand for `getElementById`. Try `var wrapper_content = $$('#wrapper img');`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are asking about adding a style to images that are children of the element with the id 'wrapper':

```
$('wrapper').select('img').each(function(name,index) {
  name.style.display = "inline";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using a combination of Geek Num 88 and T Gibbons answers for a few years. its a combination of css selectors and setting the style display value is more obvious.

```js
$$('#wrapper img').each(function(name) {
  name.style.display = "inline";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img style="display: none;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/128/Home.png" />
</div>
```